# Library Project Reference in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I know something like this is already asked many times on SO, but I've tried everything (been at this for three hours now) and I still didn't find a solution. I'm quite new to xCode and I'm starting to work on a project that was originally created by somebody else.

So, I have a library project in my xcode (XS2Library) and now I would like to reference to that library in my other project (WaarBenJij). Building the Library succeeds and I reference to it by adding the LibXS2Library.a to the Project target's "Link Binary With Libraries".

Xcode doesn't give me any errors, so it looks like the library project is referenced appropriately. However, when I try to build my project I get the error that a class that resides in my library project cannot be found ("'XS2URLLoader.h' file not found").

Can anybody steer me in the right direction, maybe?

[image: Link Binary with Libraries]

[image: Project]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

There's a sensible difference between the .a file, which is needed for linkage and contains the library source, and the .h file, which is needed to compile (and preprocess) and which contains the functions and classes declarations.

Here you included the .a file, which is required for a later step, but to use the library you also need to import the required .h files into your project.

The easier way is to simply put them in your project.

Or you can add the whole library as a subproject *and* as a dependency.